A confusion in Swinnerton-Dyer's textbook on algebraic number theory

(The above picture is cutting from Swinnerton-Dyer's classical book "A brief guide to algebraic number theory" on page 50.)
Here $k$ is a number field and $V_k$ is its adele ring. Lemma 26 states that $k$ is discrete in $V_k$. My confusion is the conjecture mentioned above,
since my understanding is that the strong approximation theorem exactly says that $k$ is dense in $V^w$. (a proof can be found for example in the book <> by Cassels and Frohlich.)
Did I misunderstood the above sentence in the picture?

You are right that this is the strong approximation theorem for global fields. Not sure what Swinnerton-Dyer had in mind. Maybe for more general fields?
